# How can I convert my MongoDB find operation after converting from using an object to an array

Tags: mongodb

I changed my MongoDB subdocument to an array from an object.

Here is what it looked like originally.

```
"transactions": {
    "TX1234": {
        "guid": "TX1234",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": false
    },
    "TX1235": {
        "guid": "TX1235",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": true
    }
}
```

I used to use this programmatic find operation.

```
var email_sent_lookup = {};
email_sent_lookup['transactions.' + transaction_guid + '.email_sent'] = true;
if(Donate.findOne(email_sent_lookup)){
    return true;
}
```

How can I convert this to find inside of my array (which now looks like below)?

```
transactions: [
    {
        "guid": "TX1234",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": false
    },
    {
        "guid": "TX1235",
        "amount": 102,
        "email_sent": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

e.g:

```
MyCollection.findOne({ 
    transactions: { 
        $elemMatch : {
           email_sent: { $eq: true },
        }
    }
});
```

or shorthand:

```
MyCollection.findOne({ 
    transactions: { 
        $elemMatch : { 
            guid: 'TX1234',    // find the GUID
            email_sent: true   // did you send it? DID YOU SEND IT?!?
        }
    }
});
```